# Issue in Xcode 4.6 build settings

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.6

In my application i have changed provision profile and changed inside build settings-->Code sign identity where any SDK and any ios SDK. Where release and distribution it's updated But it's not updated in Debug and SDK. So build is always failed.
Please help me.

[image: Below picture gives some idea]

Comment: check if you bundle identifier is same as of provisioning profile

Comment: yes, both are same only

Comment: Try changing 'Any SDK' under Debug to 'Any iOS SDK', Clean the proj, and try once. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Distribution provisioning profiles for your Debug and Release modes.  That's designed to upload to the App Store.  Instead, download a Developer provisioning profile from the same place you got the Distribution profile.  Use both of them.